# How to bypass “Adobe Flash Player has stopped a potentially unsafe operation.” running on Mac 10.7 with local files

Tags: macos, flash, local-storage

I am tearing my hair out.  I have a complicated Flash player application which I want to run on my local Mac, 10.7.4.  I set this up a year or so ago on earlier Mac OS, with earlier Flash players, and sometimes I had to fiddle with global settings, etc, but it always worked.  But now flash has decided (sensibly) to handle the security settings surrounding this use of Flash from the local System Preferences.  Here's the appropriate screen which *should* let me tell Flash that I am opening files in the folder:

[image]

You can see my desperate attempts to get flash to let me open files in /Users/peter/BTDE2/ etc -- all failing.
Why? How do I get around this? or do I just give up on flash as a horrible bad job...

It appears from the documentation at http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlayer/LSM/WS6aa5ec234ff3f285139dc56112e3786b68c-7ff0.html#WS6aa5ec234ff3f285139dc56112e3786b68c-7feb that there **should** be a fix. According to this, there should be a 'Developer Tools' control on the 'Advanced' panel, which gives access to 'Trusted Location' settings.  Well, here is the Advanced panel in Flash System Preferences and it shows no such choices.  Looks like someone screwed up somewhere.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the Flash Player panel are you not able to scroll down to reveal the Developer Tools?
[image: Dev Tools]